# Connect to SQL Anywhere 12 via Hibernate - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: JZ00L

Tags: java, hibernate, sap-ase

I have problem with connecting to remote SQL Anywhere 12 database via Hibernate.

Environment:
SQL Anywhere - version 12.0.1.4183.
Java - version 17.0.1.
Hibernate - version 5.5.9.Final.

I connected to this database via Sybase Central, so it is configured properly, I got proper credentials and remote access from my IP address is enabled.

I am trying to connect using jdbc jconn4.jar, which I have from SAP website from SDK for Adaptive Server Enterprise 16.0 SP04 PL01.

Error which I am getting.

```
18:40:37.630 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.5.9.Final
18:40:37.893 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.orm.deprecation - HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
18:40:38.216 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
18:40:38.399 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
18:40:38.406 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001005: using driver [com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver] at URL [jdbc:sybase:Tds:<database_ip>:<database_port>/<database_name>]
18:40:38.407 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=dba}
18:40:38.407 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
18:40:38.409 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
18:40:38.515 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a connection as the driver manager is not properly initialized
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:116) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746) [hibernate-core-5.5.9.Final.jar:5.5.9.Final]
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12) [classes/:?]
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8) [classes/:?]
    at Main.main(Main.java:23) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131) [idea_rt.jar:?]
18:40:38.542 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
18:40:38.558 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: JZ00L
18:40:38.558 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - JZ00L: Logowanie nie powiodło się.  Sprawdź SQLWarnings związany z tym wyjątkiem w celu wyjaśnienia przyczyn.
18:40:38.559 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 4002, SQLState: 01000
18:40:38.559 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - B��d SQL Anywhere -103: Niew�a�ciwa nazwa u�ytkownika lub has�o
18:40:38.559 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 010HA
18:40:38.559 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - 010HA: Serwer odrzucił żądanie zastosowania funkcji wysokiej niezawodności.  Zmień konfigurację bazy danych lub zrezygnuj z sesji w trybie wysokiej niezawodności.
18:40:38.567 [main] ERROR HibernateUtil - Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Logowanie nie powiodło się.  Sprawdź SQLWarnings związany z tym wyjątkiem w celu wyjaśnienia przyczyn.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:832)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processLoginAckToken(Tds.java:5578)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.doLogin(Tds.java:728)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:582)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:529)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleHAFailover(SybConnection.java:3860)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:382)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:282)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 36 more
```

hibernate.cfg.xml (ofc I changed vulnerable data to markups)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sybase:Tds:<database_ip>:<database_port>/<database_name></property>
        <property name="connection.username"><database_user></property>
        <property name="connection.password"><database_password></property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="model.old.GrGrupy" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<GrGrupy> criteria = builder.createQuery(GrGrupy.class);
        criteria.from(GrGrupy.class);
        List<GrGrupy> items = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

GrGrupy.java

```
package model.old;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "gr_grupy")
public class GrGrupy {
    @Id
    private int Indeks;
    private String Nazwa;

    public GrGrupy() {
    }

    public GrGrupy(int indeks, String nazwa) {
        Indeks = indeks;
        Nazwa = nazwa;
    }

    public int getIndeks() {
        return Indeks;
    }

    public void setIndeks(int indeks) {
        Indeks = indeks;
    }

    public String getNazwa() {
        return Nazwa;
    }

    public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
        Nazwa = nazwa;
    }
}
```

Other options which I tried

1. Use IntelliJ build in database tool and got the same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdMyW.png) (jconn4.jar)

2. Use jconn3.jar which I get from remote server from SQL Anywhere installation directory C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\java. Ofc changed driver_class to com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver. Result is just the same as earlier.
3. Use jTds jdbc. Error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:sybase:jtds:<database_ip>:<database_port>/<database_name>]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 21 more
```

4. Use sajdbc.jar jdbc. With driver_class sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver. Error below (do not have that .dll file).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc12 in java.library.path: /Users/filon/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver.try_load(IDriver.java:454)
    at sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver.<clinit>(IDriver.java:395)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
    at HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 7 more
```

5. Changed dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect. Rest of config the same as mentioned in main example. Result the same as main example.

I am newbie to hibernate config. Do you guys, have any other idea how to connect or what to try next?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Comment: Using jconn3 or jconn4.jar from the remote installation dir is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in hibernate.cfg.xml. Had to change.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sybase:Tds:<database_ip>:<database_port>/<database_name></property>
```

to

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sybase:Tds:<database_ip>:<database_port>?ServiceName=<database_name></property>
```

So the problem was not in driver. com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver works just fine. Thank you for your help.

Best Regards